# Whether to capitalize foreign words

Tags: capitalization

Are Sanskrit words or yogic terms to be capitalized or italicized within the body of an English text?

Comment: Why Would You Capitalize Some sanskrit Word Unless It Were A Proper Noun?

Answer (score 1):

As is common language convention, only capitalize proper nouns, even when words from one language are being referenced in the context of another.