# Capitalization in food

Tags: capitalization, names, food

Morning everyone!

Translating a Spanish restaurant menu into English, I found myself doubting whether to capitalize sauce names. Some examples are *romesco* and *Sriracha*.

Not being familiar with them, I looked them up and found out that romesco sauce comes from the Catalonian Spanish region, while Sriracha comes from the same-name Thai town where it was created.

In these searches I found Sriracha always being capitalized, and romesco not necessarily.

Would anyone have an input on the topic?

Thanks and regards!

Lau

Comment: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some%20cheddar%20cheese%2Csome%20Cheddar%20cheese&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20cheddar%20cheese%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20Cheddar%20cheese%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csome%20cheddar%20cheese%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20Cheddar%20cheese%3B%2Cc0), showing how ***cheddar cheese*** has replaced ***Cheddar cheese*** over recent decades, may be relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should types of cheese be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188491/when-should-types-of-cheese-be-capitalized)

Comment: Hello, Laura. There are no a priori  'English' rules hereabouts, just the 'When in Rome, ...' maxim. Here, (1) See if there is a legal requirement to capitalise either product. (2) If not, capitalise _Sriracha_ and investigate to find what dictionaries / the majority of the users do with _R/romesco_'.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384189/whether-to-capitalize-foreign-words

Answer (score 3):

There is no more reason to capitalize romesco sauce than there is to
capitalize tartar sauce, soy sauce, tomato sauce, cream sauce, picante
sauce, diavolo sauce, puttanesca sauce, or rémoulade sauce.  It doesn’t
work like Caesar salad, French dressing, Dijon mustard, German potato
salad, or Italian parsley.

That’s because you only capitalize that first word when it’s already a
proper noun or else an adjective derived from a proper noun.
Counterexamples in the realm of sauces include Worcestershire sauce,
Hollandaise sauce, or Bolognese sauce.

That’s because *romesco* doesn’t originate as some foreign-looking synonym
of *Roman*.  To begin with, it’s either Spanish (and so pronounced 
/roˈmesko/) or Catalan (and so pronounced /ruˈmɛsku/) in immediate origin,
and of course Latin more distantly. The OED defines the word as:

> In Spanish (esp. Catalan) cookery: a piquant sauce of red peppers, nuts,
>   garlic, and other ingredients. More fully ***romesco sauce***.

Its etymology is given as:

> **Origin:** Of multiple origins. Partly a borrowing from
>   Spanish. Partly a borrowing from Catalan. **Etymons:** Spanish
>   *romesco*; Catalan *romesco*, *romèscol*.
>
> **Etymology:**  <  Spanish *romesco* (*a*1894)
>   and its etymon Catalan *romesco* (1862 (in a Spanish context) or
>   earlier), variant (with loss of final consonant) of an unattested form
>   **romèscol*, ultimately  <  an unattested post-classical Latin
>   form **remisculum* in sense ‘mixture’ ( <  classical Latin
>   *re-*  + post-classical Latin *misculare*  meddle v.).

None of its citations capitalize the word. Here are the two most recent ones:

> - 1995   R. W. Kern *Regions of Spain* viii. 168   A unique dish is *calçotada* (green onions blackened over a fire and served with a spicy nut sauce known as *romesco*).
> - 2006   *Decanter* June 128/2   Grilled green vegetables and chicken are adorned with crunchy *romesco* sauce.

Lastly, if you ever use a Romance-style term like:

- French: *créme anglaise*, *sauce hollandaise*, *à la russe*, *à la Chateaubriand*.
- Spanish: *crema catalana*, *salsa fresca*, *salsa parisina*
- Italian: *pizza alla marinara*, *pesto alla trapanese*

Then you are trying to use the original non-English term in English so you
should be careful to preserve the original capitalization, which occurs
only for proper nouns; there is no concept of proper adjectives there.

Comment: So why not say Sandwich? Perhaps there are different rules when the proper noun is not qualifying another noun? If so would you say frankfurter but Frankfurter sausage?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I guess sandwiches have been with us long enough that we accept them for what they are. Note Fumble's point about *cheddar cheese*. Similarly I don't think we normally capitalise *Cardigan* - for the thing that you wear. And as for *Hamburgers* - aren't they now called *burgers*?