# Does Bourbon-Dijon sauce need to be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

Wondering if Dijon needs to be capitalized in our menu. "...served with a bourbon-dijon sauce."

Comment: Yes, because they are both proper names. Bourbon the drink and Dijon mustard. **Served with a sauce of Bourbon and Dijon mustard**. Hmmm. I'll have to try that.  If you put the sauce at the end, you would need dashes.

Comment: Thanks! What are your thoughts on same scenario "maple-brandy vinaigrette?"

Comment: Ashley, I can guarantee you with this palavering we will be shut down. But, OK: is that maple syrup?? A vinaigrette of brandy and maple syrup. [Maybe bourbon doesn't need a capital b only Dijon, name of a place]. Gosh, I love this but it is really not kosher around here. I think you need the word syrup and mustard otherwise, you have a tree and a town. You know?

Comment: I apologize! Thank you for your help!

Comment: The American whiskey, bourbon, usually has a lower-case *B*.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bourbon

Comment: Yes, bourbon lower case. I changed my mind. But not with Dijon mustard. Sorry. burgundy is a color, not the same thing. You use dijon mustard if you like, I'll stick to the capital letter: moutarde de Dijon.

Comment: Duplicate: [Capitalization in food?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503046/capitalization-in-food?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Capitalize *Dijon* but not *bourbon*: *bourbon-Dijon sauce*.

Ingredient name capitalization is a matter of style, however most style guides run along these lines:

> Personal, national, or geographical names, and words derived from such
> names, are often lowercased when used with a *nonliteral* meaning. For
> example, the cheese known as “gruyère” takes its name from a district
> in Switzerland but is not necessarily from there; “swiss cheese”
> (lowercase *s*) is a cheese that resembles Swiss emmentaler (which
> derives its name from the Emme River valley). Although some of the
> terms in this paragraph and the examples that follow are capitalized
> in W*ebster’s*, Chicago prefers to lowercase them in their nonliteral
> use.
>  <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of
> Style*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org) (login required)</sub>

Here’s a partial list from *The Chicago Manual of Style*:

> bordeaux
>  brie
>  brussels sprouts
>  burgundy
>  champagne
> cheddar
>  dutch oven
>  frankfurter
>  french dressing
>  french
> fries
>  french windows
>  gruyère
>  scotch (*but* Scotch whisky,
> a product of Scotland)
>  stilton
>  swiss cheese (not made in
> Switzerland)
>  wiener

Check with sites that have editors on duty. Here are a couple examples:

> *These rib eye steaks are marinated in a delicious bourbon-Dijon mixture . . .*
>  <sub>[— The Spruce
> Eats](https://www.thespruceeats.com/bourbon-dijon-rib-eye-with-herb-butter-336332)</sub>
>
> *1 ½ teaspoons Dijon mustard . . . 2 teaspoons bourbon*
>  <sub>[— *New York Times* Cooking](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1015848-grits-cakes-with-country-ham-and-bourbon-mayonnaise)</sub>
>
> *1/2 cup bourbon . . . 1 tablespoon Dijon mustard*
>  <sub>[— Epicurious](https://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/bourbon-and-brown-sugar-barbecue-sauce-359849)</sub>

Expanded musings at [Grammarphobia — How to capitalize food names](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/11/food-names.html)

Sometimes the authorities get involved: [*New York Times* — Is Gruyère Still Gruyère if It Doesn’t Come From Gruyères?](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/12/business/gruyere-cheese-us-court-ruling.html)

Comment: Shouldn't "dijon" be lowercase according to CMOS, then? The terms "dijon sauce" and "dijon mustard" are in fairly common use, and neither product literally comes from Dijon any more than cheddar comes from Cheddar.